# MySQL SELECT BETWEEN two points

Tags: mysql, join

Table places

```
pid   pname  
1     Amsterdam  
2     London  
3     Miami   
4     Bonn    
5     Oslo   
6     Madrid   
7     Lisbon
```

Table roots

```
    id   from    to     projectid  
    2    1       3      1 //Project#1 starts from Amsterdam  
    3    3       2      1 //Project#1 ends at London  
    4    3       5      2 //Project#2 starts from Miami and ends at Oslo    
    5    3       5      3  
    6    5       6      3    
    7    4       2      4  
    8    2       4      5   
    9    6       4      6  
    10   4       5      6
```

I need a resultset that contains all start and end points, ie:

```
start   end    projectid  
1       2       1 //Amsterdam London  
3       5       2 //Miami Oslo  
3       6       3  
4       2       4  
2       4       5  
6       5       6
```

And so, I need a list will show all projects between two cities, for example between London and Bonn:

```
4       2       4  
2       4       5
```

Comment: Those are two different questions, what have you try? Or want us to do all the work for you?

Comment: What must I do? I have two questions related each other. Must I post two questions for each one?

Comment: Yes questions are related but you arent showing any effort to solve any of those. This isnt a free write code service. Try something and when you get stuck ask for specific help.

Comment: I am working on tihs for 48 hours, and ok, I am going to edit the post right now. Thank you.

Comment: If you already try for 48 show us your work and why that didnt solve your problem, so we dont spend time trying those things again, Also that give us a picture of the what kind of problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assume the id are in sequential order

Using variables you assign a rowid to know what is the first and the last entry of each project.

`JOIN` both together choose the `from` from `F` and the `to` from `T`

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bd8b/14)**

```
SELECT F.`from`, T.`to`, F.`projectid`
FROM (
      SELECT `id`, `from`, `to`, `projectid`,
              @row := IF(@prev = `projectid`,
                         @row + 1,
                         IF( @prev := `projectid`, 1, 1)
                        ) as rn
      FROM roots R
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row = 0 , @prev = 0) x
      ORDER BY `projectid`, `id`
    ) F
JOIN   
    (
      SELECT `id`, `from`, `to`, `projectid`,
              @row := IF(@prev = `projectid`,
                         @row + 1,
                         IF( @prev := `projectid`, 1, 1)
                        ) as rn
      FROM roots R
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row = 0 , @prev = 0) x
      ORDER BY `projectid`, `id` DESC  -- HERE ID is DESC to get last entry
    ) T
  ON F.`projectid` = T.`projectid` 
 and F.`rn` = 1
 and T.`rn` = 1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| from | to | projectid |
|------|----|-----------|
|    1 |  2 |         1 |
|    3 |  5 |         2 |
|    3 |  6 |         3 |
|    4 |  2 |         4 |
|    2 |  4 |         5 |
|    6 |  5 |         6 |
```

**NOTE**

Change demo query  to `SELECT *` so you can check what is happening. Sometimes last entry equal to first entry.

For your second question depend on if you only count when city are in the first or end.

```
   SELECT *
   FROM <previous query>
   WHERE (`from` = @CityA and `to`= @CityB )
      OR (`from` = @CityB and `to`= @CityA )
```

Because if you want something considering cityes in between is much more complicated

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much.